# How should I adjust my variables in order to make it so if any word fits the criteria in them, the program appends it to a new list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I apologize if my question is worded weirdly, I'm new to Python and this is the first time in Stack overflow. Long story short, I have a function that creates a list (called word_list) of words a user makes (ex. 'tree', 'dog', 'Alaska' etc.) The function find_row is supposed to find what words in word_list can be created only using one row of keys on a keyboard. My problem is that no matter what words (excluding quertyuiop, asdfghjkl, and zxcvbnm) are typed in, the for loop will always print "Word can't be made with one row"

Here is my code:

```
def find_row(word_list):
first_row = 'qwertyuiop'
second_row = 'asdfghjkl'
third_row = 'zxcvbnm'
new_list = []
for word in word_list:
    if word in first_row:
        new_list.append(word)
    elif word in second_row:
        new_list.append(word)
    elif word in third_row:
        new_list.append(word)
    else:
        print("Word can't be made with one row")
return new_list
```

I've tried make the variables first_row, second_row, and third_row lists in order to see if that would help, however that didn't seem to change anything. I also tried to make the if statements say "if word in first_row and word not in second_row and word not in third_row" but that didn't help. (I also did that for the other two elif statements) The only time the program works as intended is if I type in qwertyiop, asdfghjkl, or zxcvbnm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're looking for a set operation. For your example you can use [`set.issuperset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) to check if the word can be constructed from the row characters:

```py
def find_row(word_list):
    first_row = set('qwertyuiop')   # <--- convert your rows to sets
    second_row = set('asdfghjkl')
    third_row = set('zxcvbnm')

    new_list = []
    for word in word_list:
        if first_row.issuperset(word):
            new_list.append(word)
        elif second_row.issuperset(word):
            new_list.append(word)
        elif third_row.issuperset(word):
            new_list.append(word)
        else:
            print(f"Word {word} can't be made with one row")

    return new_list

print(find_row(['tree', 'lag', 'cx', 'qaz']))
```

Prints:

```
Word qaz can't be made with one row
['tree', 'lag', 'cx']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this for me, I appreciate it so much! I must've spent two hours yesterday trying to figure it out.